# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement thread (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for thread

Tags: python

I wrote my program in python 3.6.2,i want install thread pakage by:

```
pip install thread
```

but i get error bellow:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement thread (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for thread
```

also use command bellow :

```
pip3 install thread
```

but again get error top.
how can fix it?

Comment: there is no package name thread
https://pypi.python.org/simple/thread/

Comment: Python 3 already comes with a threading module, is that what you want? https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading

Answer (score 1):

The module `thread` is a built in module: no need to import.
Also, the thread module has been renamed to _thread in Python 3.

If you want to use the module thread in python 3, just `import _thread` at the beginning of your script.

Example:

```
import _thread
t_pid = _thread.start_new_thread( job, () )
```

More information:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/thread.html
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/_thread.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as `$pip` is concerned its a package manager that search [this index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) for public open source packages, but there is no package name [thread](https://pypi.python.org/simple/thread/)

For Python3 threading you can follow this simple [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_m%E2%80%A6)